# Sort multiple delimited file lexicographically by one column, numerically by another

Tags: text-processing, awk, sort, text-formatting, columns

I wish to sort the TSV file below (called `min_ex`) by the first column lexicographically and by the second column numerically.

```
A X, N    2.2
A, N    5.7
A, A    5.8
A, N    2.1
A, T    0.2
B G, M    2.3
B, L    0.1
B, I    0.2
B, M    9.3
B, C    9.9
```

I tried to do it with `sort -k1,2 -n min_ex`. but it doesn't work as it results in:

```
A, A    5.8
A, N    2.1
A, N    5.7
A, T    0.2
A X, N    2.2
B, C    9.9
B G, M    2.3
B, I    0.2
B, L    0.1
B, M    9.3
```

I <s>also think</s> am also pretty sure (through experimentation) that `sort` is taking any blank space as the delimiter, but I don't see an option to set the separators.

I'd like to have solutions using either pure AWK or no-`sed` at all (preferably both, separately), and I'd like to remain as POSIX compliant as possible.

Comment: Could you clarify what’s wrong about the sort order used in your example output? It seems to be sorted correctly...

Comment: @StephenKitt Take for instance the first key, the first element is `A`. Then, in this group, I'm getting `5.8>2.1>5.7`.

Comment: Oh, OK, so really you want to sort by the first field lexicographically, using tabs, spaces and commas as separators, and by the last field numerically; does that reflect your intentions more accurately? (“First field” in a tab-separated file means that your first field here is “A, A”, “A, N” etc., not just “A”.)

Comment: It does reflect what I wrote more accurately, but not my intentions. I made a mistake. Please give me a few minutes to rethink this. @StephenKitt

Comment: @StephenKitt I asked the wrong question. Thank you.

Comment: Your code does **not** actually work, `sort sort -k1,2 -n` will sort a line like `A, A    15.8` before `A, A    5.8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

does the trick, and it’s [POSIX-compliant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) apart from the `$'\t'` part. `-t` specifies the field delimiter (instead of blank-to-non-blank transitions, which is the default); the `n` suffix can be applied to single field definitions.

Comment: Given this exchange of comments, perhaps it is important to mention that I'm on WSL (Ubuntu distro). Is this something I should be adding to the question?

Comment: @Kusalananda that’s a bit of a brown-paper-bag moment there (we need that as a hat this December)...

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why `sort -t$'\t' -nk2 min_ex` does *not* sort by the numerical column?

Comment: @user330157 in the file you posted on filebin, you had your lines terminated by CR/LF (DOS mode), and 4 spaces instead of Tabs. I've already mentioned that in an answer, but I removed it, since it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: @user330157 also `-nk2` is not the same as `-kn2`.